# Azure Dev Ops Release Issue Using Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: azure, azure-devops, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use Entity Framework Core migrations to maintain a database on Azure. This is done via Azure Dev Ops.

I have a build pipeline which uses a .Net Core project to build migration scripts this. This part works and it creates the relevant scripts to the Azure location  'D:\a\1\migrations\CarehomeBookingContext.sql'

On the build side I am using the Dev Ops component Generate Migration Scripts. To keep it simple I have set the Target folder as 'D:\a\1\migrations'. The files get set here and I get the confirmation in the log that the files have been created in the correct location.
[Confirmation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHBmJ.png)

On the release side I keep it simple and use the same location but get the error  'No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\1\migrations\CarehomeBookingContext.sql'

[Azure Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbaMM.png)

[Script location on task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZdsu.png)

So the migrations are being created in the mentioned location. But for some reason they can not be executed by the release although the release is referencing the same location that they get created in.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "Drop" is your build artifact name, you missed a part in the path, which is typically your build pipeline name with a underscore.

$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias)/drop/migrations/CarehomeBookingContext.sql

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have made the change but now get this error :  ##[error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a\_Build Carehome Room Bookings - Test\drop\migrations\CarehomeBookingContext.sql

Comment: I did try but it didn't work. I have modified my question and simplified the location where the files are being created to.

Comment: Hi build and release can not share the file like that. They are different process with different agents. you need to publish the build artifact, and download it in release

Comment: I have now got this working. Thanks to LarryX. So as LarryX points out the the build needs to be published and then downloaded. My mistake was pointing at the wrong build artifact. Once I followed the mentioned I worked out the issue.